Integrating Auth0 with the Django admin interface
I have a Django application and I am trying to change the authentication flow to use Auth0. Unfortunately, I haven't found any tutorials on how to implement this. Currently, users log in with username/password and receive a session token. I would like to change this so users are redirected to Auth0, login there, receive the session credential, and are then redirected to the admin UI.
Does anyone have any experience with this? I am very stuck.
